# Custom login for Apache Superset?

Tags: flask, apache-superset

I'm running Apache Superset 1.4.1 on a Debian server.

I am attempting it on Ubuntu 20.04 VMs behind a proxy. And I am running superset on http://localhost:9000/(in dev mode)

How to reproduce the bug

1 Clone Superset repository

2 cd superset

3 docker-compose up

4 in another terminal(cd superset/superset-frontend)

5 npm run dev-server

Superset Supported Authentication Types:

```
Database,
Open ID
LDAP
REMOTE_USER
OAUTH
```

The user wants custom login with image captcha. So where do I make changes to create a custom login? I suspect this would be handled on the Flask side of things but I am unable to find any help on how to approach this challenge.

I am a Flask novice so any pointers will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Superset has integration with major authentication backends such as database, OpenID, OAuth and REMOTE_USER. There however are scenarios where all these approaches are not supported by your organization and need to implement a custom approach. you can follow this tutorial for implementing your custom authentication servicr
https://www.justanothersapien.com/2019/08/02/authenticate-apache-superset-with-a-custom-user-store/